CSS property: display: none Cypress error - Cannot click Add buttons to add products to basket
I'm currently building a e2e regression test suit for an eCommerce website developed in Angular JS, I have written a loop and provided a condition in it, this is my code:
           const productText = $el.find('.productName').text()
           if(productText.includes('Cookie')) {
              cy.wrap(productText).get('.add-btn').contains('Add').click()
             
           }
     })```

The website UI is a table view so I'm looping through this table view by tr, and then I also provided a locator there .productName which is the product name basically and  if any of the product names on in this table contain "Cookies" word then find the Add button and click to add to basket.

Interestingly if adds the first product at index 0 from the table tr but then when it moves to the next iteration then I get this error:

"Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible:

<span ng-if="!(!(price.Stock > 0) &amp;&amp; product.AllowBackOrders &amp;&amp; !bypassStock)" translate="" class="ng-scope">Add</span>

This element <span.ng-scope> is not visible because its parent <button.btn.btn-primary.add-btn.hide> has CSS property: display: none"

The locator is the same for all the buttons I have checked this many times, but then if I use click({force: true}), this still add only the first prodiuct to the basket and then find those products which meet the if statement but it does not click on their add button to add them as well into the basket.

Can someone help with this probably is simple but I'm just stuck here with this, here is a video I have recorded: https://vimeo.com/936771058/081f79e031?share=copy


A lot of your test is missing so it's hard to tell, but I would say to start with a visibility check since the error is all about the the element not being visible.
cy.contains('.productName', 'my-product')
  .find('.add-btn').contains('Add')
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()

or just bypass the visibility check if it does not compromise your test
cy.contains('.productName', 'my-product')
  .find('.add-btn').contains('Add')
  .click({force:true)


Hi , thanks for coming back on this problem, afyer many tries i have found the correct locator now and it works, loops through the product table then respects the if statement and clicks the add buttons to each of those products i need to push into my basket. I have just provided the whole class name but then on the official Cypress website I see that best practice to use the data-cy to make sure we interacting with the element we need. Thanks again!
